# Multidimensional Arraylist and DropdownLists

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, multidimensional-array

My question is, how can do I take this Multi Dim array collection and apply level 2 to a drop down list,

```
 var someArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
        { label: "Level 1 p1", data: 
         { label: "Level 2", data: "some stuff" }
        },
        { label: "Level 1 p2", data: 
         { label: "Level 2", data: "some stuff" }
        }
    ] );

<s:DropDownList includeIn="items" id="classSelect" dataProvider="{someArray[0].data}" selectedIndex="0" labelField="label" x="405" y="150"/>
```

someArray[0].data - for example points it to the entry 1 and the contents of the data level which in turn is a arrayList again, is my understanding here of how the pointers are working incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> Apply level 2 to a drop down list

If you want to display the level 2 text in the drop down you can do so with an itemRenderer or a [labelFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html#labelFunction) which drills down into the object to return the text.  Conceptually something like this:

```
protected function getLevel2(item:Object):String{
  return item.data.label;
}

<s:DropDownList dataProvider="{someArray}" labelFunction="getLevel2" />
```

If you want the [dataProvider](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableDataContainer.html#dataProvider) to contain nothing but your nested objects, then you'll have to loop over the someArray value and create a new collection containing only the level 2 objects.  Conceptually like this:

```
var newDataProvider :ArrayCollection = new AryCollection();
for each (item in someArray){
 newDataProvider.addItem(item.data);
}
```

I'll also add, as a point of clarification that your current setting of the dataProvider most likely provides a error because your 'data' is a generic object which does implement the [IList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/IList.html) interface.

```
<s:DropDownList dataProvider="{someArray[0].data}" />
```

If it did work, then you'd end up with a dataProvider that only has a single item in it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I went with the loop that seems to have resolved my issue :p:

Comment: @John Yes; I wrote all the code in the browser; so there may be syntax errors than a IDE would have caught immediately.

Comment: @John If you have a follow up question; feel free to ask it.  If you have an unrelated question, feel free to post a new question to StackOverflow. ( But there is no guarantee I'll answer, but it is likely someone else will). If you want to hire me for private/confidential help; contact me privately at: http://www.asktheflexpert.com/contact.cfm